# X,Y have joint distribution, means,variances u1,u2,o1,o2, correlation coeff. p &E(Y|X) linear function. show E(Y|X)=u^2+po2/o1(X-u1)

Tags: statistics

Suppose X and Y have a joint distribution with finite means and variances respectively given by u1,u2,o1,o2 with correlation coefficient given by p. Further suppose that E(Y|X) is a linear function in X. I have to show that E(Y|X)=u^2+p(o)2/(o)1(X-u1). I also have to then show that E(Var(Y|X))=(o)2^2(1-p^2).
where o is a symbol (omega I think)